# bubbleSort() for an int Array Linked List in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble with a bubbleSort method for my *very unique* homework assignment.

We are supposed to use a sorting method of our choice to sort, get this, a linked list of int arrays. Not an ArrayList not just a LinkedList. It works like a linked list but the each Node contains an array of a capacity of 10 ints.

I am stuck on the sorting method. I chose bubbleSort just because it was used in the last assignment and I felt most familiar with it. Any tips for a better sorting method to try would be considered helpful as well.

Here is my code:

```
public void bubbleSort() {

        current = head;                     // Start at the head ArrayNode
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {    // iterate through each ArrayNode
            currentArray = current.getArray();  // get the array in this ArrayNode

            int in, out;    
            for (out = size-1; out > 1; out--) {        // outer loop (backwards)
                for (in = 0; in < out; in++) {              // inner loop (forwards)
                    if (currentArray[in] > currentArray[in+1])  // out of order?
                    swap(in, in+1);                             // swap them!
                }
            }
            current.setArray(currentArray);
            current = current.getNext();
        }
    }// End bubbleSort() method

// A helper method for the bubble sort
private void swap(int one, int two) {
    int temp = currentArray[one];
    currentArray[one] = currentArray[two];
    currentArray[two] = temp;
} // End swap() method
```

This is a picture example of what I am supposed to be doing.
[image: Growable Linked List of Arrays]

Comment: sorry what are you sorting?

Comment: ints in an array which are contained in a Node (like from a linked list). Each Node has one array of 10 ints.

Comment: so how do you/are you supposed to sort the arrays? By length? Compare each element with each other?

Comment: You may want to check out [Quick Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) or [Merge Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) for better sorting algorithms (both of which are O(nlog(n)) as opposed to O(n^2) for bubble sort), or you could always just use Arrays.sort if you don't need to write it yourself.

Comment: I'm supposed to write it myself. :-/ I'd be happy to just get the individual arrays sorted for the time being. I have NO clue how I could sort them across all Nodes and arrays.

Comment: @Moritz, sort the ints in ascending order across all the array nodes.

Comment: Post a little example to better understand your problem. An input and the expected output.

Comment: @rendon picture example posted.

Comment: @MagdaleneB. Well, this is how your linked list of arrays works, but you are trying to sort numbers, is this your problem?: INPUT: `[9, 3, 2] -> [11, 12, 4] -> [21, 0, 85] -> ... -> [88, 100, 7]` OUTPUT: `[0, 2, 3] -> [4, 7, 9] -> [11, 12, 21] -> ... [85, 88, 100]`.

Comment: I am not only expected to sort the numbers in ascending order of the arrays in the nodes, but all the arrays in all the nodes need to be in ascending order. Yes like that @rendon.

Comment: You might find this app very helpfull(assuming you have android) to help you understand how something works: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=wiki.algorithm.algorithms

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution with selectionsort. There are a few test values, just run it to see it.
I can provide further information if needed.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class ArrayedListSort {

int listsize = 5;  // how many nodes
int maxValue = 99; // the highest value (0 to this)
int nodeSize = 3;  // size for every node

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // run non static
    new ArrayedListSort().runTest();
}

/**
 * Log function.
 */
public void log(Object s) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
public void logNoBR(Object s) {
    System.out.print(s);
}

/**
 * Output of list we have.
 */
public void logMyList(ArrayList<ListNode> listNode, String name) {
    log("=== LOG OUTPUT " + name + " ===");
    for ( int i=0; i < listNode.size(); i++) {
        logNoBR(" node <" + i + ">");
        logNoBR(" (");
        for (int j=0; j < listNode.get(i).getSize(); j++) {
            if ( j != (listNode.get(i).getSize()-1)) // if not last add ","
                logNoBR( listNode.get(i).getValueAt(j) + "," );
            else
                logNoBR( listNode.get(i).getValueAt(j) );
        }
        log(")");
    }
    log("=====================================\n");
}

public void runTest() {
    // create example List

    ArrayList<ListNode> myList = new ArrayList<ListNode>();

    // fill the nodes with random values
    for ( int i = 0; i < listsize; i++) {
        myList.add(new ListNode(nodeSize));
        for (int j=0; j < nodeSize; j++) {
            int randomValue = new Random().nextInt(maxValue);
            myList.get(i).addValue(randomValue);
        }
    }
    logMyList(myList, "myList unsorted"); // to see what we have

    // now lets sort it
    myList = sortListNode(myList);

    logMyList(myList, "myList sorted"); // what we have after sorting
}

/**
 *  Selectionsort 
 */
public ArrayList<ListNode> sortListNode(ArrayList<ListNode> myList) {
    ArrayList<ListNode> retList = new ArrayList<ListNode>();
    for ( int i = 0; i < listsize; i++) {
        retList.add(new ListNode(nodeSize));
    }
    int lastSmallest = myList.get(0).getValueAt(0);

    while ( !myList.isEmpty() ) {
        int lastJ=0, lastI=0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
            for (int j=0; j < myList.get(i).getSize(); j++) {
                if ( myList.get(i).getValueAt(j) <= lastSmallest ) {
                    lastSmallest = myList.get(i).getValueAt(j);
                    lastJ = j;
                    lastI = i;
                    //log("Found smallest element at <"+i+","+j+"> (" + lastSmallest + ")");
                }
            }
        }
        myList.get(lastI).removeValue(lastJ);

        if ( myList.get(lastI).getSize() == 0 )
            myList.remove(lastI);

        // add value to new list
        for ( int i = 0; i < listsize; i++) {
            if ( retList.get(i).getSize() < retList.get(i).getMaxSize() ) {
                retList.get(i).addValue(lastSmallest);
                break;
            }
        }
        lastSmallest = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    }
    return retList;
}

public class ListNode {
    private ArrayList<Integer>  values  = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private  int                    maxSize;

    public ListNode(int maxSize) {
        this.maxSize = maxSize;
    }
    public ArrayList<Integer> getValues() {
        return values;
    }
    public int getMaxSize() {
        return maxSize;
    }
    public int getSize() {
        return values.size();
    }
    public int getValueAt(int position) {
        if ( position < values.size())
            return values.get(position);
        else
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
    public void addValue(int value) {
        values.add(value);
    }
    public void removeValue(int position) {
        if ( position < values.size()) {
            values.remove(position);                    
        } else
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here we go. The trivial solution consist in extracting all the elements of each array node and store them in a single big array, sort that big array (using Bubble Sort, Quick Sort, Shell Sort, etc.) and finally reconstruct the linked list of arrays with the the sorted values. I am almost sure that is not exactly what are you looking for.

If you want to sort the numbers *in place*, I can think of the following algorithm:

As others have commented, you need a comparison function that determines if a node **A** goes before a node **B**. The following algorithm use the first idea but for each pair of nodes, e.g. `A->[3, 9, 7]` and `B->[1, 6, 8]` becomes `[1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]` and finally `A->[1,3, 6]` and `B->[7, 8, 9]`. If we apply this rearrangement for each possible pair will end up with a sorted linked list of arrays (I have no proof, though).

```
A = head;
while (A.hasNext()) {
    arrayA = A.getArray();
    B = A.getNext();
    while (B.hasNext()) {
        arrayB = B.getArray();

        // concatenate two arrays
        int[] C = new int[arrayA.size() + arrayB.size()];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < arrayA.size(); i++)
            C[i] = arrayA[i];
        for ( ; i < arrayA.size() + arrayB.size(); i++)
            C[i] = arrayB[i-arrayA.size()];

        // sort the new arrays using agains Bubble sort or any
        // other method, or Arrays.sort()
        Arrays.sort(C);

        // now return the sorted values to the two arrays
        for (i = 0; i < arrayA.size(); i++)
            arrayA[i] = C[i];
        for (i = 0; i < arrayB.size(); i++)
            arrayB[i] = C[i+arrayA.size()];
    }
}
```

This is kind of pseudo code because I haven't worked with linked lists in Java but I think you get the idea.

**NOTE:** I haven't tested the code, it may contain horrors.